# Every time I try to go to certain websites, Firefox gives me the server not found

Tags: firefox

I just did an install of Ubuntu 20.04 today and I’m trying to get some software downloaded. I can’t connect to any of the sites I need to. Only stuff like Google and Facebook. Please tell me any information I need to give I haven’t done this before.

Comment: Could you try a different wifi hot spot? Does `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` work? Could you try Google chrome?

Comment: I tried all except the hotspot I don’t have access to another currently. I’m getting the same result.

Comment: does upgrading works as usual?

Comment: Yes it seems normal to me

Comment: Try google chrome or chromium

Comment: Sounds like a DNS issue

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a new "feature" in Firefox that uses Cloudflare DNS servers. See [this web page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-dns-over-https) for more details. Also assure that your Proxy settings are correct.

Go to Firefox preferences, choose General, Network Settings, Settings, and disable "DNS over HTTPS". Retry your various web sites.

[image]